# How to make labels and radio buttons visible/invisible and with toggle slide function at same time?

Tags: jquery

Given a checkbox in a table row, and three radio button on next table row. while loading the page the radio buttons are invisible.

How to create an on click function which can make the radio buttons visible along with slide up slide down effect?

```
<td>
<input type="checkbox" id="appalert" name="appalert" value="appalert"  onclick="toggleRadioButtonPanel(this);"> alert
</td>

<td>
<label class="alertTypePanel" style="visibility: hidden">alertType: </label>
<input type="radio" name="alertTypeOpt" id="alertTypeOpt1" class="alertTypePanel" value="Ticker" style="visibility: hidden">
<label class="alertTypePanel" style="visibility: hidden" style="visibility: hidden">Ticker</label>
<input type="radio" name="alertTypeOpt" id="alertTypeOpt2" class="alertTypePanel" value="Pop up" style="visibility: hidden">
<label class="alertTypePanel" style="visibility: hidden">Pop up</label>
</td>
```

Comment: Did you try the aptly-named `slideToggle()` method?

Answer (score 0):

```
<td>
    <input type="checkbox" id="appalert" name="appalert" value="appalert" class="appalert"> alert
</td>

<td>
  <div class="toggle" style="display:none;">
    <label class="alertTypePanel">alertType: </label>
    <input type="radio" name="alertTypeOpt" id="alertTypeOpt1" class="alertTypePanel" value="Ticker">
    <label class="alertTypePanel">Ticker</label>
    <input type="radio" name="alertTypeOpt" id="alertTypeOpt2" class="alertTypePanel" value="Pop up">
    <label class="alertTypePanel">Pop up</label>
  </div>
</td>

$('.appalert').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().next('td').find('.toggle').slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/cD8FK/)**

```
$('#appalert').click(function(){
   $('label, input:radio').toggleClass('alertTypePanel').slideToggle();
});​​​​

<table>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" id="appalert" name="appalert" value="appalert" > alert
</td>

<td>
 <label class="alertTypePanel" >alertType: </label>
 <input type="radio" name="alertTypeOpt" id="alertTypeOpt1" class="alertTypePanel"     value="Ticker" >
<label class="alertTypePanel" >Ticker</label>
<input type="radio" name="alertTypeOpt" id="alertTypeOpt2" class="alertTypePanel" value="Pop up" >
<label class="alertTypePanel" >Pop up</label>
</td>
</tr></table>

.alertTypePanel{
 display:none;
}​
```